# outlier cell in three20

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, three20

I sometimes see the following issue in my cell using three20:

[image]

The TTStyledTextLabel is empty or has no text.. it should have something in there as the others have.

The code is very simple:

```
 TTStyledText * text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:group.name lineBreaks:YES URLs:NO]; 
        text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18.0];
        _main_title.text = text;


- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    _avatar.urlPath = nil;
    [_avatar removeGestureRecognizer:self.tapGesture];
    self.accessoryView = nil;
    UIImageView * lock = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:-1];
    UIImageView * star = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:-2];
    UILabel * star_creator = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:-3];
    if (lock != nil)
        [lock removeFromSuperview];
    if (star != nil)
        [star removeFromSuperview];
    if (star_creator != nil)
        [star_creator removeFromSuperview];

    int index = -4;
    TTImageView * avatar = (TTImageView *)[self viewWithTag:index];
    while (avatar != nil){
        [avatar unsetImage];
        index--;
        avatar = (TTImageView *)[self viewWithTag:index];
    }
    [_avatar unsetImage];
}
```

Comment: edited with code (that's all I do to set the _main_title.text with a TTStyledText, and this is inside setObject

Comment: that one should have a text "convore tech & dev question", not sure if the & is the problem here as the other cell's had no &

Comment: or another possibility is because of the prepareForReuse? As this cell I believe is from another re-used cell... I didn't do anything to the main_title during prepareForReuse

Comment: post the code you are using in prepareForReuse

Answer (score 1):

By default the text color the white, so it might be showing up, but you just can't see it :-)

Try changing the text color:
    _textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];

Also, note that if you're using TTStyledText, you can't use a standard UIKit label. You need to use TTStyledTextLabel from the three20 library, as such:

```
_textLabel = [[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] init];
_textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
_textLabel.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
_textLabel.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
_textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:_textLabel];

_textLabel.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:@"MY TEXT HERE" lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES];
[_textLabel sizeToFit];
_textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:18.0];
_textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: then why is it that it works for all the other cells and just this one?

Comment: I mean the cell above and below this outliar one

Comment: and yes main_text here is a TTStyledTextLabel

Comment: wait, what? i don't understand

Comment: which one don't you understand?, I updated the screenshot so it's a bit clear now

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the text is not nil or has any special characters that might not make it past your json/xml parser.

Comment: duoble checked and it's not nil